# CardStackView null

Tags: kotlin, null, fragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), CardStackListener {


val cardStackView = card_stack_view

val manager = CardStackLayoutManager(getActivity(), this)

private val adapter by lazy { CardStackAdapter(createSpots()) }

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val homeFragmentView : View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)


    cardStackView.layoutManager = manager
    setupCardStackView()
    setupButton()
    return homeFragmentView
}
```

*Error message is "cardStackView must not be null"
The error is in the "cardStackView.layoutManager = manager"
What can i do for resolving this problem...  *

Comment: What is `card_stack_view`?

Comment: I use yuyakaido library

Comment: Why not directly use card_stack_view?

Comment: i modify card_stack_view now. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Never say "it doesn't work" **without a detail**.

Answer (score 0):

add a question mark after `cardStackView` like this:

```
cardStackView?.layoutManager = manager
```

I guess `cardStackView` is nullable and IDE says this line may results `NullPointerException`

Comment: The error message OP shown "cardStackView must not be null" is a runtime error msg, in my memory.

Comment: @GenoChen I do not see in the question that it is a run time error. so it may be a compile time error

Comment: @GenoChen i do not see `NullPointerException` or Exception in question. also in Kotlin `NullPointerException`  happens rarely because null check is done at compile time

Answer (score 0):

Can you add which CardStackView you are using? There are several libraries that implement such a view (some of them have good documentation, like https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView and https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView).

You could look for examples of a [CardStackView for Android being used on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20CardStackView) or by using Google.

**Update**
The issue could be caused by the manager field possibly being null. What happens if you do the initialization completely within the function?

```
val manager = CardStackLayoutManager()
val adapter = CardStackAdapter()

val cardStackView = findViewById<CardStackView>(R.id.card_stack_view)
cardStackView.layoutManager = manager
cardStackView.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: I use yuyakaido library!